# Slick Slider - how to make child element appear outside slick-list (with hidden overflow)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I need to make a downward triangle indicating the current slide. And the slider has a background color that expand to full width of the screen. The triangle is actually "popping" out of the slider. Please see attached image for example. Also added the code sample I have.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bawpKq

However, since the slick-list has `overflow:hidden`, I had to force it to be visible for the triangle to show up. But that won't work if there're more slides outside slick-list. Please let me know if anyone has a different way to approach this. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used a different approach - create a separate element for background, use absolute position and set `height: calc(100% - 20px)` where `20px` is the height of the triangle.

See the last slider in this example

https://codepen.io/litdane/pen/bawpKq